# Which of the following is correct option?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, examples-counterexamples

> Let $f_1,f_2$ be two real  valued functions defined on the real
>   line.Define two functions $g,h$ by $g(x)=max${$f_1(x),f_2(x)$} and
>   $h(x)=min${$f_1(x),f_2(x)$}.Then
>   $g(x^2)+h(x)^2+3g(x)h(x)=f_1(x)^2+f_2(x)^2+3f_1(x)f_2(x)$ holds for
>   all $x\in \mathbb R$
>
> $1.$Always
>
> $2.$ only of $f_1(x)=f_2(x)$ for all $x\in \mathbb R$
>
> $3.$only $f_1$ and $f_2$ are both positive functions or both negative
>   functions.
>
> $4.$ only if atleast one of the functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ is
>   identically zero

Solution:

if we choose $f_1(x)=1,f_2(x)=2$,then  $g(x^2)+h(x)^2+3g(x)h(x)=2+1^2+3(2)(1)=9$

and

$f_1(x)^2+f_2(x)^2+3f_1(x)f_2(x)=1^2+2^2+3(2)(1)=11$,

So,

$g(x^2)+h(x)^2+3g(x)h(x)\neq f_1(x)^2+f_2(x)^2+3f_1(x)f_2(x)$

Hence,option $1,3,4$ get discarded so,the only remaining option i.e option 2.

must be true.

But, **it is given that option $1$ is true.**

Please point out my mistake

Comment: may be, it should be hold if the rhs is $f_1(x^2)$ and $f_2(x^2)$ instead of $f_{1}^2(x)$ and $f_{2}^2(x)$. And you can always prove the statement if you remain mot sure.

Comment: @:Reza Habibi:there is no tyo in the post,i wanted to know what is "wrong" with my counterexample?

Comment: I suspect that it's _supposed_ to be $(g(x))^2+(h(x))^2+3g(x)h(x)$. The moment you start to much about with the _argument_ to one of the functions but not the other, then things usually become very unequal very quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Hint, assuming my comment above is true: Note that $f_1(x)+f_2(x)=g(x)+h(x)$ and $f_1(x)f_2(x)=g(x)h(x)$.